# Flutter FireStore: The method 'where' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I use the code, I can receive the data correctly.
However, using `.where`, I get the error:

> The method 'where' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'where'.

code:

```
chamaBancoDeDados(curso, materia, id, dificuldade) {
    Map<String, dynamic> dados = {};
    final documentoRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('cursos')
        .doc(curso)
        .collection(materia)
        .doc(id)
        .where('dificuldade', arrayContainsAny: ['normal']);
    documentoRef
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documento) {
      if (documento.exists) {
        try {
          dados = documento.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          print("dados são: $dados");
        } on StateError catch (e) {
          print('Erro tentando adquirir o documento no banco de dados: $e');
        }
      } else {
        print('O documento não existe no banco de dados');
      }
    });
    return dados;
  }
}
```

I've already searched a lot on the internet, including the Firebase documentation, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Without the `where` the code should already be returning the document with the `id` you specify. What do you expect the `where` statement to change about that return value?

Comment: I hope to filter the data. I'm taking tests that will have different levels of difficulty. So, I want to receive only certain tests with the defined difficulty level.

Comment: Even without the `where` condition, the code already only returns a single document snapshot (the one with the `id` you specify). Please explain what you expect the `where` to change about that, in Firestore terms. Do you expect no documents if `id` is not of normal difficulty? Do you expect some subset of the fields of the document? etc

Comment: I don't just want a document. I'm creating a database of questions, with levels of difficulty. Some questions maybe have the difficult  level and the demo version. Thus, a question can have either the "normal" or "demo" difficulty array. And I don't want to put the difficulties in a collection. I want it to be field items, because I can modify the difficulty level in the future, or remove the "demo".
At this moment, I want to query my database and pull documents with the desired difficulty level. So, I want not just a document, but a set of documents, seletect by the .where.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code tries to read a single document with a known ID, in which case there is no way to further filter the data with a `where` clause. So if you only want to read that single document, remove the `where`:

```
final documentoRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('cursos')
    .doc(curso)
    .collection(materia)
    .doc(id);
```

If on the other hand, you want to read all documents from the `cursos` collection with a normal difficulty level, that be done by removing the `.doc(id)` clause:

```
final documentoRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('cursos')
    .doc(curso)
    .collection(materia)
    .where('dificuldade', arrayContainsAny: ['normal']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see in `line 7` of your code, that gets a document from firestore, and you cant use `.where()` on a document.

`.where()` is used for collections to check the condition for all documents (in that collection) and return the documents which satisfy the need.

From the above given info, I'd suggest you to remove `7th line` of code and try again.

Please share your Firestore hierarchy so that we could suggest a better way to perform your queries.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, if I remove the .where(), the code works fine. The problem is: I want to use-it! I need the .where() and I  couldn't know how to use correctly.

Comment: Is it that you want to find a document in `.collection(materia)` in which the condition is applied? How does your firestore hierarchy look like?

Answer (score 0):

I make this and works how I wanted:

```
    final teste = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('cursos')
    .doc(curso)
    .collection(materia)
    .where('dificuldade', arrayContainsAny: [dificuldade]); 
await teste
    .get()
    .then((event) {
    print("${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}");
  }
}, onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"));
```